# How to map certain Kega Fusion functions to a gamepad?

Tags: controllers, emulation, sega-genesis, kega-fusion

I'm using *Kega Fusion*, a Sega Mega Drive/Genesis emulator, which has specific hard-coded keyboard presses for a certain functions (e.g. <kbd>Backspace</kbd> = Fast Forward, <kbd>F5</kbd>/<kbd>F8</kbd> = save/load state, etc.).

Is there any way to map these keyboard presses to a gamepad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a hint in the comments, 
the [JoyToKey](https://joytokey.net/en/) program was used to remap my controller to the desired keyboard inputs.

As an added bonus, the remap also only occurs when a specified program is running (in my case, the Kega Fusion emulator), as shown below.

[image]